# Question on fixed effects modelling

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Assume we have the following model:

\begin{equation}
  Y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{it} + \alpha_{\text{country}_i} + \alpha_{\text{industry}_i} + \gamma_t + u_{it}
\end{equation}

We have country, industry and time fixed effects. Observations are companies. Dependent variable = Output in terms of production.

Generally, there can be overlaps between country and industry affiliation, or in other words, all industries are contained in each country. Is that not problematic for modelling, as we will have a lot of repetition? Could this lead to multicollinearity?

I have had an idea: Can this issue maybe be fixed by creating unique pairs of country-industry affiliation for each company? For instance, I could make a new variable called "country-industry", which captures the pairwise information for each company. More specifically, this could be "US-Agriculture" for a simple firm. Next, I could include this "country-industry" variable as a fixed effect, instead of country and industry by themselves.
Is this approach feasible and does it lead to the same result as the other approach?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Why would all industries be within a country?  E.g. there is a car industry in the US, Japan, many European countries, Korea, etc. etc.

Comment: @PeterFlom fair point. What I meant by this is that each country has all of the industries included. While some industries might be a lot more relevant for some countries than for others, each industry is contained in each country.

Comment: That's a good thing.

Comment: I think it depends on your research question and context. For example, if the government subsidizes some industries but that investment variable is not in your data, the latter makes sense. If there are worldwide shocks from oil prices that impact agriculture more than tech, the first is more reasonable.

Comment: @dimitriy thanks, I understand your reply, but could you explain how you arrive at this conclusion? I was hoping for a theoretical explanation, but textform would also be fine

Comment: I don't think there is much theory in my answer, economic or econometric. Subsidies are a country-industry-specific variable since governments only invest in politically connected industries in their own countries. In the US, for example, farmers get many subsidies, while tech does not. Subsidies increase output. If you had subsidies for each firm in your data, you would use it as a control. But that is rare, so you would use industry-country FEs to pick up the time-invariant effect of industrial policy on output.

Comment: In contrast, oil is a single global market. A shock to the price of oil hits some industries harder than others: manufacturing, transportation, and agriculture (via petroleum-based fertilizer) might have large but different effects since their costs all go up, but software may have zero impact. So you might want to put in industry-time FEs for this. Covid might be another example of this.

Comment: Finally, firms in some industries dwarf others in a different sector. Without an industry effect, your model imposes that a hedge fund and a school in the same country have the same output if they have identical Xs. The point is that FEs should correspond to some economic model or story about what's happening and your research question.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, makes a lot of sense.